# What is the geometric description of the set of isomorphism class of $G$-torsors over a site $C$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, principal-bundles, grothendieck-topology, gerbes

Let $X$ be a topological space and $G$ be a topological group. Let $\tilde{G}$ be the sheaf of groups defined by the sheaf of sections of the product $G$ bundle $ \pi_1:X\times G \rightarrow X $.

**(1)** Let $T\tilde{G}_X$  be the set  of all isomorphism class of $\tilde{G}$-torsors over $X$.

**(2)** Let $H^1(X,\tilde{G})$ be the $\tilde{G}$ valued  non-abelian cohomology of degree $1$ over the $X$.

**(3)** Let $BG_X$ be the set of all isomorphism class of Principal $G$ bundles over $X$.

Now it is well known that there exist one-one correspondence between **(1) ,(2)** and **(3)**.

Now let we replace the *topological space* $X$ by a *site* $C$ then the definition of sheaf over a site is well known. Hence I am *assuming*  that we can *appropriately* generalise $(1)$ and $(2)$ to the (1') and (2') as follows:(*Though neither I have proved it personally nor I have seen anywhere where such generalisation is mentioned.* )

**(1')** Let $T\tilde{G}_C$  be the set  of all isomorphism class of $\tilde{G}$-torsors over $C$.

**(2')** Let $H^1(C,\tilde{G})$ be the $\tilde{G}$ valued  non-abelian cohomology of degree $1$ over  $C$.

**Now my question is the following:**

*Is there any analogue of* **(3)** *if we replace the topological space $X$ by a site $C$?*

I will also be very grateful if someone can suggest some literature in this direction.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your $G$ when you want to define notion of a $\widetilde{G}$-torsor over $\mathcal{C}$ when $\mathcal{C}$ is a site? Is it just a group object in the category $\mathcal{C}$? Do you want to give a reference from where you are borrowing your definitions 1,2 and 3?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I am actually not sure about what $G$ is when $C$ is a site. My reference for 1,2 and 3 is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212266

Comment: What distinction is being drawn between definitions (1) and (3)?

Comment: @WillSawin Sir, by (1) I mean a $\tilde{G}$-torsor i.e sheaf $S$ over a topological space $X$ with an action of a group valued sheaf $\tilde{G} $over $X$ and an existence of an open cover $\cup U_{\alpha}$ of $X$ such that each $S(U_{\alpha})$ is non empty. Now from a $\tilde{G}$ torsor we can produce an element of $H^1(X, \tilde{G})$ and from that element we can produce a principal $G$ bundle $\pi:P \rightarrow X$ where $P$ is a topological space obtained from the data given by the element of $H^1(X,G)$ and $\pi$ is a continuous function from $P$ to $X$. This $\pi:P \rightarrow X$ is my (3).

Comment: Sure, but (1) is just the sheaf of sections of (3). If you forget the topological space and pass to the site, these definitions are pretty much indistinguishable.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes I agree that (1) is the sheaf of section of (3). Actually this is my question " When we pass to site "Is indeed (1) and (3) are indistiguishable or there exist some notion of the form $\pi':P' \rightarrow X'$ where  $P'$, $X'$  may  be some categories and $\pi'$ is a functor. Also we may replace $G$ by Higher Groups like 2 groups or something of that sort.

Comment: @WillSawin Can you expand on what do you mean by “ forget the topological space and pass to the site”?

Comment: @WillSawin Sir, can you please give me little details about why do you think when we pass to site from topological space, (1) and (3) becomes indistinguishable? Also what do you mean by (3) when we pass to site? Unless I understand what is meant by (3) (in the context of site) I am not able to understand (3)=(1) in the context of site.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I just mean that there is not so much data about a map of spaces $Y \to X$ that can be expressed naturally in the language of the site of $X$ (rather than in the language of the space of $X$). The main data that would be preserved would be the sheaf of sections of $Y$, as well as the site of $Y$ and its map to $X$. But the second definition seems inappropriate for defining groups and torsors.

Comment: @WillSawin when you say site of $X$ you mean the category $\mathcal{O}(X)$ of open subsets of $X$ equipped with some Grothendieck topology or the topological stack $\underline{X}\rightarrow \text{Top}$ associated to the topological space $X$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I don't know what the second one is so I guess I mean the first.

Comment: @WillSawin Sir, I have edited my question by writing some extra paragraphs at the end. It would be very helpful if you kindly go through my edits at your leisure.

Comment: "But the second definition seems inappropriate for defining groups and torsors." I do not completely understand this... Given a group $G$, one can consider the sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$, defined as $\mathcal{G}(U)=\{\text{smooth maps } U\rightarrow G\}$. Then, there is a notion of $H^1(X,\mathcal{G})$.. The paper "Introduction to Language of stacks and gerbes" by Moerdijk says this set $H^1(X,\mathcal{G})$ is in one-one correspondence with the the set of isomorphism classes of $G$-torsors on $X$.. So, in what sense (2) is inappropriate here? @WillSawin

Comment: What do they mean when they say site? site of what? If on the site $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A})$ (here $\mathcal{C}$ is a category and $\mathcal{A}$ is a Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{C}$) does not have any extra structure, why would they call a sheaf of groups on $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A})$ to be a "geometric" group?

Comment: I guess you are really asking if there is some "geometric" object $\mathcal C/G$ for any site $\mathcal C$? In this generality, I don't think the question even makes sense. The paper you link to are working with $\infty$-topos and there the question makes sense. In general in any geometric category, you can ask if there is some object that represents the functor in your defn (1).

Comment: @Asvin I am trying to understand your comment. But can you explain in little detail what do you mean by geometric category? Is it the same thing as mentioned in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+category? Also is there any precise definition of geometric object in a category?

Comment: @Asvin Also you mentioned "In general in any geometric category, you can ask if there is some object that represents the functor in your defn (1)". I did not get what did you mean by  the "functor" in my defn (1).

Comment: I am just using geometric category roughly but it generalizes sets/topological spaces/schemes with zariski or etale topology /manifolds/infty spaces/whatever. The functor just assigns to a map T to X, the set of G torsors of T.

Comment: @Asvin. Ok. I have asked the later part of this question as a different question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359056/confusion-in-understanding-the-notion-of-g-principal-bundle-where-g-is-a-geo

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The sheaf $\mathcal G$ is what I mean to call the first definition. I agree the first definition is very appropriate for defining torsors. The second definition is the site of $G$, which involves considering open subsets of the group $G$, or $G \times X$. I think this is not so helpful because (at least in AG) products of sites are not so well-behaved.

Comment: @WillSawin It looks like I need to read a little more.. Can you suggest some reference for "(at least in AG) products of sites are not so well-behaved."... It is expected to be not so well-behaved  :D Just wanted to read some more...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I just mean that open sets on $X \times Y$ in the Zariski topology don't arise from the products of open sets on $X$ and open sets on $Y$, which you can find explained in any introduction to the Zariski topology.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes. That is the second exercise (I think) of Hartshorne's book :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read Section 4.5 of Olsson's book *Algebraic Spaces and Stacks*.

The notion of a site is a piece of category theory with no intrinsic geometry, so it doesn't really make sense to ask for a geometric description of torsors for a general site.

However, in the concrete geometric contexts where site theory is typically applied, you can generalize definition 3). It will always imply definitions 1)-2) (which are always equivalent, essentially by the definition of Čech cohomology), but the converse becomes a non-trivial question about descent.

Let's assume you have some category $\mathscr{S}$ of spaces and to each object $X$ of $\mathscr{S}$, you attach a site $\mathrm{Op}(X)$ consisting of a certain full subcategory of $\mathscr{S}/X$ (e.g. the site of open subsets of a topological space, the site of étale maps into a scheme/algebraic space/DM stack, etc). Let's also assume that for a morphism $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$, the pullback map $U \mapsto f^{-1} U := U \times_Y X$ defines a continuous morphism of sites $f \colon \mathrm{Op}(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Op}(Y)$, i.e. that if $U$ is an object of $\mathrm{Op}(X)$, then $f^{-1} U$ is an object of $\mathrm{Op}(Y)$ and that covers pull back to covers. (There are interesting contexts where this is not true, e.g. the crystalline or lisse-étale sites; in such cases, you need to be extremely careful!)

Moreover, assume that to any map of spaces $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$, the presheaf $h_X$ on $\mathrm{Op}(Y)$ defined by $U \mapsto  \mathrm{Mor}_Y(U, X)$ is a sheaf, where $\mathrm{Mor}$ is the set of morphisms in $\mathscr{S}$. We say that $X$ *represents* the sheaf $h_X$ (note that $X$ might not be unique; the Yoneda lemma would only apply if $X$ is an object of $\mathrm{Op}(X)$).

If you want to state this abstractly, we're requiring that we have a fibered category over $\mathscr{S}$ with fiber $X \mapsto \mathrm{Op}(X)$, that this is a full subcategory of the natural fibration $X \mapsto \mathscr{S}/X$ with the same notion of pullbacks, and that this fibration satisfies the stack/descent condition for morphisms.

If $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf of groups on $\mathrm{Op}(X)$, the equivalent definitions 1) and 2) give a notion of when a sheaf $\mathcal{P}$ on $\mathrm{Op}(X)$ is a $\mathcal{G}$-torsor.

On the other hand, if $G$ is a group object in $\mathscr{S}/X$, we can make the following geometric notion of a $G$-torsor: a $G$-torsor is a map $P \rightarrow X$ in $\mathscr{S}$ with an action of $G$ given by a map $\rho \colon G \times_X P \rightarrow P$ (which is compatible with multiplication on $G$ in the sense that the evident diagrams commute) such that:

1. The map $(1, \rho) \colon G \times_X P \rightarrow P \times_X P$ is an isomorphism.
2. There is a covering $\{U_\alpha\}$ in $\mathrm{Op}(X)$ such that the map $P \times_X U_\alpha \rightarrow U_\alpha$ has a section (pulling back the isomorphism from point 1. along this section then gives an isomorphism $G \times_X U_\alpha \rightarrow P \times_X U_\alpha$).

Now, the sheaf $h_G$ is a sheaf of groups on $\mathrm{Op}(X)$, and the sheaf $h_P$ is a $h_G$-torsor in the sheaf-theoretic sense. Now, it makes sense to ask the following question:

If $G$ is a group object in $\mathscr{S}/X$ and $\mathscr{P}$ is an $h_G$-torsor, is there some $G$-torsor $P$ in $\mathscr{S}/X$ such that $\mathscr{P} = h_P$?

This is now a question of *descent* in $\mathscr{S}$.

Namely, since $\mathscr{P}$ is an $h_G$-torsor, we may find a covering $\{U_\alpha\}$ in $\mathrm{Op}(X)$ such that for each $\alpha$, we may choose a trivialization $h_G|_{U_\alpha} \simeq \mathscr{P}|_{U_\alpha}$. Therefore, $\mathscr{P}|_{U_\alpha}$ is represented by the trivial geometric $G|_{U_\alpha}$-torsor $P_\alpha = G|_{U_\alpha} \rightarrow U_\alpha$, with $G|_{U_\alpha}$-action given by left multiplication. The descent data for $\mathscr{P}$ gives us a Čech cocycle $(g_{\alpha \beta})$ with $g_{\alpha \beta} \in h_G(U_{\alpha, \beta}) = \mathrm{Mor}_X(U_{\alpha, \beta}, G)$, where $U_{\alpha, \beta} = U_\alpha \times_X U_\beta$. This is the same thing as a $G|_{U_{\alpha, \beta}}$-equivariant isomorphism $P_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha, \beta}} \rightarrow P_\beta|_{U_{\alpha, \beta}}$ in $\mathscr{S}/U_{\alpha, \beta}$. In particular, these isomorphisms satisfy the triple overlap condition because $(g_{\alpha \beta})$ is a cocycle.

If this descent datum is effective, then there is an object $P$ of $\mathscr{S}/X$ representing $\mathscr{P}$. This will always be a geometric $G$-torsor (note that this doesn't immediately follow from the Yoneda lemma, since $G$ and $P$ may not be objects of $\mathrm{Op}(X)$):

The action maps $\rho_\alpha \colon G|_{U_\alpha} \times_X P_\alpha \rightarrow P_\alpha$ glue to a map $\rho \colon G \times_X P \rightarrow P$: apply the fact that representable presheaves are sheaves to the open cover $\{G|_{U_\alpha} \times_X P_\alpha\}$ of $G \times P$. Moreover, the same argument shows that the map $(1, \rho) \colon G \times_X P \rightarrow P \times_X P$ is an isomorphism.

When you're dealing with topological spaces and open subsets, descent is always effective (in abstract terminology, the fibration $X \rightarrow (\mathscr{S}/X)$ is a stack). This is often not true in algebraic geometry!

For example, let's take $\mathscr{S}$ to be the category of schemes with the fppf topology. If $G \rightarrow X$ is *affine*, then we know that fppf descent is effective, and thus any sheaf-theoretic torsor $\mathscr{P}$ is represented by a geometric torsor $P \rightarrow X$. This is also true (it's a hard result of Raynaud) if $X$ is Dedekind and $G \rightarrow X$ is an abelian scheme, but it can fail in general. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19339/torsors-in-algebraic-geometry) MO question and section III.4 of Milne's book *Etale Cohomology*.

It's a hard theorem of Artin (using the full force of his deformation-theoretic representation criteria for algebraic spaces) that fppf descent is effective for algebraic spaces, so we can in fact represent all sheaf-theoretic torsors for a group algebraic space $G$ by geometric torsors which are algebraic spaces. (See Tag 04SJ in the Stacks Project).

**Edit** Since you mention it in the question, I should add that this whole conversation should carry over essentially verbatim in a higher-categorical context (for example, you could replace the group $G$ by $BG$, and then talk about $G$-gerbes instead of torsors and look at cohomology in degree $2$). I'm not an expert in these things, but certainly Lurie discusses the matter comprehensively in Higher Topos Theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and references of the literature you mentioned. I will definitely go through those. I partially understood your argument. I am trying to understand it fully.

Comment: Thanks for  adding the remark on higher category  theory perspective of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, too long for a comment.

If we start with an arbitrary site $\mathcal{C}$ and if we want to define the notion of a $G$-torsor over $\mathcal{C}$, then $G$ is not expected to be a group object in the category $\mathcal{C}$.

Observe that when $\mathcal{C}=\underline{X}$ for a topological space $X$, when you define $G$-torsor over the topological space $X$, the candidate $G$ was **not a group object in the category $\underline{X}$**. Instead, we have a fibered category $\underline{X}\rightarrow \text{Top}$ and **$G$ is the group object in the category $\text{Top}$**. The Grothendieck topology on $\text{Top}$ gives a Grothendieck topology on $\underline{X}$. This is the Grothendieck topology on $\underline{X}$ we are assuming when defining (the usual) notion of sheaf on the topolgical space $X$ or the shaef on the site $\underline{X}$.

So, if you want to imitate the notion of $G$-torsor to an arbitrary site $\mathcal{C}$, it is only reasonable to expect that there is a (fibered category ??) functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ for some $\mathcal{D}$ and $G$ is a group object in the category $\mathcal{D}$. Further, the Grothendieck topology that we have fixed on $\mathcal{C}$ is expected to come from a Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{D}$.

For example, consider the case when $\mathcal{D}=\text{Man}$, the category of manifolds. Fix a Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{D}$, say open cover topology. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a differentiable stack; that is, $\mathcal{C}$ is a fibered category with the functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Man}$, satisfying certain special properties. Then, $\mathcal{C}$ can be made as a site. A cover $\{U_\alpha\rightarrow U\}$ is a cover for an object $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$ if, its image $\{F(U_\alpha)\rightarrow F(U)\}$ is a cover for the object $F(U)$ of $\text{Man}$. Then, fixing a group object in $\text{Man}$, that is a Lie group, we have the notion of a principal $G$-bundle over the site $\mathcal{C}$.

So, when $\mathcal{C}$ a category of special type, equipped with a functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Man}$ or $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow (\text{Sch}/S)$ and for a group object $G$ of $\text{Man}$ or $\text{Sch}/S$, we can define the notion of principal $G$ budnle over $\mathcal{C}$. It is not clear how one can define for sites which are not of this type.

The other two notions of $G$-torsors and $H^1(\mathcal{C},G)$ also require same assumptions as above.

References:

1. The notion of principal bundle over an algebraic stack; that is a special kind of fibered category $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Sch}/S$ can be found in section $1.2$ of [Root stacks, principal bundles and connections](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6556.pdf).
2. The notion of principal bundle over an differentiable stack; that is a special kind of fibered category $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Man}$ can be found in section $4$ of [Differentiable stacks and gerbes](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jsg/1310388899).
3. The notion of $G$-torsor over an algebraic space/algebraic stack can be found in [Definition 04TY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TY)

Comment: Thanks. I am going through your answer(Long comment).

Comment: Can you please explain in details what do you mean by Principal $G$ bundle over a site $C$? Because in standard case from a $\tilde{G}-torsor$ over $X$i.e ( a sheaf $S$ over $X$ with (1) a free, transitive action of group valued sheaf $\tilde{G}$  over $X$ and (2) existence of an open cover $\cup U_{\alpha}$ of $X$ such that each $S(U_{\alpha})$ is non empty.)  we get a Principal $G$ bundle over $X$ but not over $O(X)$. My question is what is the analogue of $X$ when $C$ is a site?

Comment: I have added the reference.. It is an abuse of notation to call a principal bundle over topological space $X$ as a principal bundle over the site $\mathcal{O}(X)$... “ My question is what is the analogue of  when   is a site?” I thought I answered that part..  $\mathcal{C}$ has to be the special catgeory that I have mentioned in the answer..

Comment: No no, I am not asking about the notion of Principal $G$ bundle over a stack. I am asking what do you mean by a Principal $G$ bundle over the site $C$ obtained from a $\tilde{G}-torsor$? I can understand what are you saying. But my point is when you consider the standard case [when your fibered category is $O(X) \rightarrow Top$] you get a principal $G$ bundle over $X$ but not $O(X).$ Then for a differentiable  stack say $C \rightarrow Man$ by the (analogous procedure) why are you getting a Principal $G$ bundle over $C$?

Comment: All I can do is repeat what I said before :P... **It is an abuse of notation to call a principal bundle over $X$ to be a principal bundle over the site $\mathcal{O}(X)$**... Once you read the  definition  of principal bundle over a topological stack or Differentiable stack, you can realise that a principal bundle over $X$ actually gives a principal bundle over the stack $\mathcal{O}(X)$.. I have not said anything about the notion of $G$ torsor over a site $\mathcal{C}$.. So, “ what do you mean by a Principal   bundle over the site C obtained from a G ~ torsor?” is not relevant..

Comment: I will try to see if I can find references for G torsor over Differentiable stack or algebraic stack and tell you..

Comment: Added reference for G torsor over an algebraic stack, that is a special kind of site.. I am seeing that definition just now, so, can’t comment more.. I will try to see the correspondence between G torsor and Principal G bundle over algebraic/Differentiable stack..

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But I think your answer and comments are in the context of $G$ torsor over a stack (considered as a special site) and Principal $G$ bundle over the stack... but I am expecting a correspondence(if possible) between a $G$ torsor over a site $C$ and Principal $G$ bundle over an object  X of $D$ where $C \rightarrow D$ is the fibered category you mentioned in the answer. ( In special case for example the site $O(X)$ comes from an Object $X$ of Top and here the fibered category is $O(X) \rightarrow D$). Though I understand for an arbitrary stack such a special object may not exist.

Comment: Typographical error in the last line of my last comment . The correct version is the following :"Though I understand for an arbitrary "site" such a special object may not exist"

Comment: You did not had definition of a principal G bundle over a stack or of a G torsor over a stack. So, I gave definitions for that.. I am trying to see if I can get notion of G torsor over a stack from principal G bundle over a stack and vice versa... Till then, I request you to go through the definitions and see if there is any confusion in the definitions..

Comment: Ok. I will go through it. Thank you.

Comment: :D Stop saying thank you :P

Comment: I have edited the question by adding some extra paragraph at the end. Kindly please go through it.