# Confusion in understanding the notion of $G$ Principal bundle where $G$ is a geometric group over a site

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, principal-bundles, gerbes, sites

The first paragraph of the section **Overview** in the paper *Principal infinity-bundles - General theory by Nikolaus, Schreiber and Stevenson* https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0248 precisely reads the following:

*The concept of a G-principal bundle for a topological or Lie group G is fundamental in classical topology and differential geometry,. More generally, for G a geometric group in the sense of a sheaf of groups over some site, the notion of G- principal bundle or G-torsor is fundamental in topos theory. Its relevance rests in the fact that G-principal bundles constitute natural geometric representatives of cocycles in degree 1 nonabelian cohomology H1(−,G) and that general fiber bundles are associated to principal bundles.*

**My confusion is the following:**

Since they are working with a sheaf of groups $G$ over a site(which they call here geometric group) so it is natural to ask what did they mean by $G$ Principal  bundle or $G$-torsor in this context(Note neither they have  mentioned about the "base space" of the $G$ Principal bundle nor about     where $G$-torsors are defined(like over a topological space or a site?).

Though I am assuming $G$ torsors are defined over a site. But do they mean that the  notion of $G$ principal bundles and $G$ torsors over a site are indistinguishable in their set up?

Or

Is there any separate meaning for $G$ Principal bundles for them?

Also they said $G$ Principal  bundles  constitute natural geometric representatives of cocycles in degree 1 nonabelian cohomology H1(−,G) . Note instead of writing $H^1(X,G)$ they wrote $H^1(-,G)$. So my guess is if $B$ is the base space of the $G$ Principal bundle then an isomorphism class of such $G$ principal  bundle over $B$ will correspond to an element of $H^1(B,G)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try reading beyond the first paragraph of the first section?

Comment: @MikeShulman Sir, I came across the notion of Principal 2 bundles from Bartels 2 bundle's (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410328) where a principal 2 bundle is defined within a category internal to some generalised smooth space and the structure group is a coherent 2-group as introduced in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307200.  Baez, Schrieber  in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0412325 introduced a notion of connection in it but restricted the base to dengenerate smooth 2 space and Loop spaces. Wockel in https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3692 also mentioned about Principal 2 bundles.

Comment: @MikeShulman Though Wockel mentioned about the general Principal 2 bundles but his  treatment was mostly on what they called semi strict principal 2 bundle over a manifold(considered as a degenerate smooth 2 space). Though I don't have much background in infinity category but  in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3692 from the  4th paragraph in the 1st section it seems that Principal infinity bundles is a generalisation of Principal 2 bundles when the structure group is something like infinity space(which they called geometric infinity groups).

Comment: @MikeShulman Now since I don't have have much background in infinity category I am not able to understand what geometric infinity group is!! I am also confused about the term geometric group . But it seems geometric 2 groups must be related to 2 groups (in the sense of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307200). Also since in the previous papers I mentioned about principal 2- bundles above they clear mentioned about their base (i.e some 2 space) but here I could not get what is the base of such Principal infinity bundles!! Is it some $(\infty,1)$ category?

Comment: @MikeShulman I am also right now not that comfortable with the language of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3692 due to use of infinity category. But I am very curious about connecting a link of how my understanding of Principal 2 bundles (in the sense of papers by Baez, schrieber, Wockel I mentioned above) with this paper on principal infinity bundles which treats the concept of principal 2 bundles  as a particular  case!

Comment: @MikeShulman Sir, should I ask these things separately in a new question?

Comment: @MikeShulman In my 2nd comment there is a correction. The link I mentioned must be replaced by https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0248 Thank you

Comment: I don't know what the point being made in of all your comments is; I was just saying that I think your original question is answered a few pages later in the paper.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you Sir. I will definitely look at the portion of the paper you mentioned. I am apologising for writing clumsily in the comments . I will  write my doubts clearly and post it as  a separate question and will mention the link here. Thank you.